# What is the best way to do a metanalysis for half-life?

Tags: r, regression, meta-analysis, environmental-data

I am working on a meta-analysis on pesticide degradation, where the quantity of interest is the difference in half-life in different environments. However I am in doubt of how to use the data; in all cases the value is estimated through the slope of a linear regression $(\hat b /0.693).$ Can I use this parameter and its variation directly? Or would other spikes be observed?

Comment: Can you clarify what model you are specifically dealing with? What variables are being used in the regression?

Comment: If you have a quantity and its standard error you can use it in standard meta-analysis packages in R. You last sentence about other spikes is not clear to me though so there may be more to this than meets the eye.

Comment: I intend to use the half-life of pesticides, which is obtained by dividing 0.693 by parameter b of first order linear equations. I would like to know if I can use this parameter directly to proceed with a meta-analysis, or are there implications? For what I have read so far has not been very clear about the use of coefficients of equations to make meta-analyzes.

Comment: And about the variables in regression, x= time and y=remain concentration of pesticides

Comment: For example use the t (1/2) of table 3, of this article10.1371/journal.pone.0219462